# How to access phpmyadmin(LAMP) from another pc within LAN network?

Tags: lamp

As above said, i want to access the PHPMyAdmin from another PC that is in the same network.

My one PC(Which i want to access) is having ubuntu(20.04). I have installed LAMP in that, and it is working fine locally.
Now i want to access that PC's PhpMyAdmin from another PC Which is in the same network.

i have edited the httpd-xampp.conf file and added the "Require all granted" But no luck.

And also httpd.conf: LISTEN IPaddress:PORT
And also httpd.conf: ServerName IPaddress:PORT

Still getting the Error of: This site can't be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo vi /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/phpmyadmin.conf
```

or

```
sudo nano /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Remove Line

```
Require local
```

Add new line

```
Require all granted
```

Comment: for me it was on lampstack-7.4.9-0/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-app.conf